# fetch a hashmap from a list in java

Tags: java, list, hashmap, rest-assured

I have a list like this being formed.
And I am getting the list items like:

```
[
{Status=ok, ModuleID=40, Details=all ok, ModuleName=Job Posting, Attributes={amount=207,360.00, creatorName=Aditya, emailId=qatest8@fieldglass.com, ref=WIT0JP00000035, uom=USD, uniqueName=aditya_b, validObject=false, iconType=procurement, name=Checklist JP Cycle, refVersion=0, startDate=2015-02-01, createDate=2015-04-08, status=Pending Approval}, ID=z15040805190698260198983},
{Status=ok, ModuleID=70, Details=all ok, ModuleName=Time Sheet, Attributes={ref=WIT0TS00000460, uom=USD, amount=400.00, validObject=false, iconType=worker, name=Checkad1, Checkad1, refVersion=0, startDate=2015-03-30}, ID=z15040609520807147341983},
{Status=ok, ModuleID=430, Details=all ok, ModuleName=Expense Sheet, Attributes={ref=WIT0ES00000028, uom=USD, amount=50,000.00, validObject=false, iconType=worker, name=Checkad1, Checkad1, refVersion=0, startDate=2015-03-31}, ID=z15040609585357352848983},
{Status=ok, ModuleID=430, Details=all ok, ModuleName=Expense Sheet, Attributes={ref=WIT0ES00000030, uom=USD, amount=51,000.00, validObject=false, iconType=worker, name=serad1, serad1, refVersion=0, startDate=2015-04-03}, ID=z15040704105392986424983}
]
```

Now I want to traverse the whole list and get the "ref" value from the Attributes section of all the lists.

How can I do this. I have written a code for this but how to go inside the Attributes section is what I am not getting.

```
List<HashMap<String,String>> rt =downloadRes.path("PAYLOAD","ModuleID");

                int length=rt.size();
                System.out.println(rt);

                for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
                {



                for(HashMap<String,String> entry:(rt))
                {
                 for(String key:entry.keySet())
                 {
                     if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("Attributes"))
                     {

                   //what to write over here so that I can get the value of "ref" from that hashmap being created.


                     }

                     System.out.println(entry.get(key));

                 }

                }
```

Comment: Your example looks like JSON, just without quotes. In case you just omitted those for your example ... and you are actually dealing with JSON data; then any decent JSON library should do that for you.

Comment: If you are planning to store the lists in a HashMap keyed by ModuleID then it won't work, because you have duplicate keys. Apart from that I'm not sure what you wish to achieve.

Comment: @GhostCat: please ignore the issue of JSON , Consider like I just have a List and I have to traverse it.I have edited the question please have a look.

Comment: So you are talking about string parsing? It is still not clear what you are asking for. Please provide an **exact** example of your input; and what the output should be.

Comment: Yeah but its not a string but a HashMap which I have to traverse and in this case I have a list in which I have 4 HashMaps and in that I have a key and a value. But in case of Key="Attributes" , I have a value as another HashMap which I need to handle. So i need to get the value of key="ref"

Answer (score 0):

This is not a recommended way to store the data you have. You are storing the whole value, "{ref=WIT....}" as String for the key, 'Attributes'. It will be a fragile way.

But assuming you DO want to store it as a String, you will have to parse that with regular expression to get back the value or 'ref'.

One possible expression is

```
(?<=ref=)(.*)(?=,[ ]*uom)
```

The assumption here is the value of ref is followed by a comma, then 0 or more spaces and then String uom.

Here is code to test it...

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
      String toParse = "{ref=WIT0TS00000460, uom=USD, amount=400.00, validObject=false, iconType=worker, name=Checkad1, Checkad1, refVersion=0, startDate=2015-03-30}";
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=ref=)(.*)(?=,[ ]*uom)");
      Matcher m = p.matcher(toParse);
      if(m.find()){
        String group = m.group(1);
        System.out.println(group);
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(HashMap<String,Object> entry: rt) {
                    for(Entry<String, Object> key : entry.entrySet()) {

                                if(key.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Attributes")) 
                                    {
                                        Map<String, String> attributes = (Map<String, String>) key.getValue();
                                        for(Entry<String, String> attri : attributes.entrySet()) 
                                        {
                                        System.out.println(attri.getValue().toString());
                                        }
                                    }

                              System.out.println(key.getValue());


                        }

                    }
```